# Error while booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, initramfs

I have a Dell Vostro 1550 laptop with an Intel Core i3 processor running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. It shows me the error message: `(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.` in BusyBox, and it also says: `Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands`.